# How to force to redraw a layer

Tags: openlayers-3

I am looking for a method that redraws all the features stored in a layer (equivalent to method "redraw" with OL2)

the method "changed" of class ol.layer.Vector "refreshes" only the features visible on a map (for instance in the zoomed part)
and thus doesn't impact the features outside

the treatment applied to those data is to delete periodically old features

how can I achieve this ?

another question is how to be notified of the end of this specific deletion ?

thanks in advance

Jean-Marie

Comment: That depends.  How do you obtain your features ?  Do they come from a file you fetch asynchronously and that the content is updated remotely ?  If so, adding a unique parameter to source url should be the right way.

Oh, and you might also want to check the FAQ, though I'm not sure if it applies to your case (but it's worth a try): https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/doc/faq.md#how-do-i-force-a-re-render-of-the-map

Answer (score 1):

first thanks for your  answers

my question requires effectively more information :

the browser client receives points through a real time websocket connection

every second, an array of new features collected from those points is added into the Vector layer in this way :

```
vectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures(features);
```

the duration of the source buffer is, for instance one hour, and to manage a temporal sliding window of one hour, old features are removed every minute

```
        map.once('postrender',removeOldFeatures);
        vectorLayer.changed(); or map.renderSync();
```

this removal is only correctly done for visible features

But as soon as some features are not visible due, for instance, to a zoom on a portion of the map where those features are not displayed, then the removal treatment (removeOldFeatures) is not executed for those features whatever the method used (vectorLayer.changed() or map.render())
as a consequence the number of features doesn't stop increasing...

Jean-Marie

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a TileVector Source and format GeoJSON. At the end i use the provided TileUrlFunction and to redraw the layer, i just set the Source again with the layer.setSource(yourdefinedSource) method. Dube is right. Most of the time (if the source is updated to often) it is useful to send a unique param (like unix timestamp) as a cachebuster.